# use sockets to read an RFID device from the network using C

Tags: c, sockets

I found an RFID reader with a finger print reader that I would like to use. I tried to use sockets to listen to the port, but I'm unsure on how can I do it properly. The device does not have any labels, so I cannot find data from manufacturer on how to establish the connection. The devices works as I have tested with another software used for clocking in, so the device has now an IP address assigned that I'm able to ping. I have tried a socket server program to listen to the port, but I'm not getting anything when I read the RFID tags. How can I read data from the device when it is connected to the network and store the data?

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
main(){
   char server_message[256] = "You have reached the server";
   //create the server socket
   int server_socket;
   server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   //define the server address
   struct sockaddr_in server_address;
   server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
   server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

   //bind the socket to our specified IP and port
   bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address,     sizeof(server_address));
   listen(server_socket, 5);
   int client_socket;
   client_socket = accept(server_socket,NULL,NULL);

   char server_response[256];
   recv(server_socket, &server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0);

   //print out server's response
   printf("The server sent the data: %s\n", server_response);



   //send the message
   send(client_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0);
   //close the socket
   close(server_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not valid C89/C90 (declarations mixed with code) and not valid C99+ (missing return type on `main()`).

Comment: "*I have tried a socket server program to listen to the port*" - what port?

Comment: you are asking us what the TCP / UDP interface is for an RFID reader, but we dont know what type of reader it is. Thats hard.! First thing I would do it look to see what ports it has open, that might give clues about what protcols it supports

Comment: If the device has ports open, you're going to need to write a client program (connecting to a host/port), not a server program (listening on a port).

Comment: I used port 9002. I was under the assumption that I could have a server socket listening/ reading the port (right now I assigned a fixed IP address to my computer and the device is connected to the ethernet port; I can ping the device) and capturing the information when the RFID tag is scanned. Do you have an example on how to get the device to talk with the computer? One of my main problems is that I have no idea who manufactured the device.